# How can one prove this directly using the definition?

Tags: general-topology

I know $e^x : \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous function of course. But how can I prove it **directly**  by using the topological definition?(I mean not using ε-δ) i.e. a mapping $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces with topology $O_X, O_Y$ respectively is continuous iff
$$\{f^{-1}(A):A\in O_Y\} \subseteq O_X$$

Comment: What properties do you know about $e^x$? Or are you working straight from the definition of $e^x$, in which case: which definition are you using?

Comment: For example, how about using $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$?

Comment: What is your definition of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Once you know how to breakup an open set into little open intervals you can try to compute the inverse image of a little interval thanks to logarithm.

Comment: @jeanmfischer Normal Euclidean topology. However I want to know what if it is Sorgenfrei or something else.

Comment: You can try to prove this more general statement : every bijective monotonous function is an homeomorphism and apply it to $x\mapsto e^x$.

Comment: (if you already know that exponential is monotonous and bijective)

Comment: @jeanmfischer Yeah, I know. I'll try that, thank you for your comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59875/discussion-between-jeanmfischer-and-ciatina).

Answer (score 1):

This is almost immediate, since on any neighborhood $(a,b)$, you have

$$ f^{-1}((a,b)) = (\ln(a), \ln(b))$$

Answer (score 0):

Proceed by contradiction. If $e^x$ is not continuous, then there is some open set in $\mathbb R$ whose inverse image is not open in $\mathbb R$.

Suppose this open set is A. Suppose the $f^{-1}(A)=B$. B is not an open set. That means there is some point x in B such that every neighborhood of x contains points outside of B. Taking intervals centered at x of length 1/n and choosing one point in each such neighborhood outside of B gives a sequence $\{x_n\}$ outside of B converging on x, which is in B. Corresponding to this, there is a sequence of points $\{f(x_n)\}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We know that 
$$|f(x_n)-f(x)| = |e^{x_n}-e^{x}| = e^{x}|1-e^{(x_n-x)}| = e^{x}(1-e^{-|x_n-x|})$$
If we want 
$$|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$
Then 
$$e^{x_n}(1-e^{-|x-x_n|})<\epsilon \Rightarrow |x_n-x| < -\ln{\left(1-e^{-x}\epsilon\right)}$$
So the condition will be satisfied if
$$|x_n-x| < -\ln{\left(1-e^{-x}\epsilon\right)}$$
We can meet this condition for all $n > N$ for some N since $\{x_k\}$ converges to x. So $\{f(x_k)\}$ converges to f(x). But since A is an open set and f(x) is a limit point of a sequence in A, there exists N such that $f(x_n)\in A$ for all $n>N$. Then $f(x_n)\in B$, for infinitely many n, a contradiction.

Comment: "B is not an open set. That means there is some limit point of B which does not belong to B."
Is that really correct? If $B = [0, 1]$, which is *not* open, then all its limit point *do* belong to $B$.

Comment: You're right.   .

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix this.